# Block Content Scraper via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently struggleing with a website which is scraping my site's content by reading the RSS feed and copying my content to their site.

Their server's IP is 5.175.25.229

What is want to do is locking them out by sending them back to their own website using a .htaccess rule.

Will this rule do the job?
`RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 5.175.25.229
RewriteRule .* http://www.the-bad-website-stealing-my-content.com/ [R,L]`

Comment: So what's the problem? it's not working?

Comment: I wonder if this is right since I can't try it myself.

Comment: You can test it with your own IP address as the remote IP if you just want to test the rule. Otherwise, it just expect it should work with any other IP if it works for yours. Also you can use a deny rule too.  Also you should escape your IP's `5\.175\.25\.229`

Comment: And with `^` and `$` or `5.175.25.2` will also lock `125.175.25.243`. Use `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^5\.175\.25\.229$`.

Comment: Thank you Panama Jack, sometimes the easiest solution is the most difficult to think of. :-)

Comment: However, this only prevents the IP from visiting my site's home, not mysite.com/feed/. How can I block access to "/feed/"?